# XSLT recursive sort by attribute

Tags: xslt, sorting, recursion, attributes, element

I found multiple questions and answers regarding nested/recursive sort using XSLT, but was not able to map it on my situation.

My situation:

- "set" element can consist of 0 or more "property" elements
- a "set" element can consist of 0 or more subsets
- both set and property elements consist of attribute "key"
- I want to sort the "set"s by "key" attribute, and per "set":   sort by "key" of "properties" elements

The XML looks something like:

```
<set key="...">
  <property key="..."/>
  <property key="..."/>
  <property key="..."/>
  <set key="...">
    <set key="...>
      <property key="..."/>
      <property key="..."/>
      <property key="..."/>
    </set>
  </set>
</set>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple situations it can be achieved like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
                <xsl:sort select="@key" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this XML:

```
<set key="1">
  <property key="6"/>
  <property key="8"/>
  <property key="1"/>
  <set key="3">
    <set key="0">
      <property key="4"/>
      <property key="2"/>
      <property key="9"/>
    </set>
  </set>
</set>
```

Result will be:

```
<set key="1">
    <property key="1"></property>
    <set key="3">
        <set key="0">
            <property key="2"></property>
            <property key="4"></property>
            <property key="9"></property>
        </set>
    </set>
    <property key="6"></property>
    <property key="8"></property>
</set>
```

**I guess real-life app is more complex, but your example doesn't show that**.

Comment: Great, thanks @Flack! Any way that you can keep the key's sorted within the set that they belong to? So, in your example: property 1-6-8 should stay together.

Comment: @Wivku: That would be grouping and sorting.

Comment: @Alejandro: what do you mean? The original question was: "and per "set": sort by "key" of "properties" elements". @Flack's answer is useful and really close, but would be great if the property elements can stay together.

Comment: @Wivku: Unclear requeriments is the reason why we always ask for a **desired output**. That leaves no doubt. Suppose there are `properties` after `set` with `@key` equal to `3`: should those be together with the first group of `properties` or they should be grouped together after the `set`?

Comment: @Alejandro: I appreciate the guidance. In the source file the properties are grouped (before the sub-sets), per the example I gave, and they should stay grouped in the output as well.

Comment: @Wivku: Then the most simplest solution involves two rules: identity (`<xsl:template match="@*|node()"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template>`) and one for `set` (`<xsl:template match="set"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:copy-of select="@*"> <xsl:apply-templates select="property"> <xsl:sort select="@key" data-type="number"/> </xsl:apply-templates> <xsl:apply-templates select="set"> <xsl:sort select="@key" data-type="number"/> </xsl:apply-templates> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template>`).

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I don't think XSL-T is suited for this sort of thing.  It's an XML transformation language, not a programming language for sorting.

I think it'd be better to use the right tool for the job: Use a language like Java or C# to produce the XML in sorted form, then use XSL-T to transform it.

If you're struggling with it, you probably should re-think the approach.

Comment: Actually, I don't mind using something else. E.g. Perl, PHP, etc. I defaulted to XSLT because I saw so many examples that come close to what I was looking for, but not quite.

Comment: I agree, but I don't think that XSL-T is the best way to do it.  You're entitled to your opinion if you downvoted the answer, but re-read the first sentence: "I don't think XSL-T is suited for this sort of thing."  That's different from saying it can't be done.

Comment: @duffymo - How experienced are you with XSLT? It is extremely well-suited for this.

Comment: Enough where I'd rather do it elsewhere.  The sort tag is one thing; recursive sorting and grouping is another.  Perhaps it's because XSLT isn't my favorite technology.  My bias might be showing.

Comment: @duffymo: I don't downvote opinions. But I think that they belongs to comments region...